# Moving the volume bar up and down has no effect - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio

When I move the audio volume bar up and down it doesn't change it at all, unless I bring it zero in which case it mutes, but other than that the loudness of the speakers stays the same. When I plug my headphone into my laptop and unplug it the volume shifts to that of set into the volume bar, but every time I want to change the volume I have to do this. How do I fix this? The laptop is a HP elitebook 840 G6.

Comment: Run the Audio troubleshooter from *Settings > System > Troubleshoot > Other troubleshooters*.

Comment: @harrymc The troubleshooter couldn't find any problems.

Comment: Try also [these steps](https://www.makeuseof.com/volume-control-slider-not-working-windows/).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your help, I think I've managed to narrow down the problem. Whenever I play something with Media Player the problem starts. If I end it with task manager the problem will be fixed. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Is in *Settings > Windows Updates > Advanced options* the option "Receive updates for other Microsoft products" is enabled, and is Windows 10 fully updated? What is your Windows 10 version?

Comment: @harrymc I enabled it but I guess it won't update the program until a new windows update is available. Windows was recently updated and the windows version is 22H2

Comment: You may check for updates for your Windows 10 and ignore the offer to pass to Windows 11 (if you get it), to ensure that you're fully updated. Note that Windows 10 is approaching its end of life, so updates will become less frequent. If the problem is too bothersome, you could use another player, such as the excellent VLC.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the old volume control installed, it might give more control.

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `sndvol.exe` and select *SndVol.exe*.

There are controls for each app, and a master volume control. See if one of those fixes the issue.

[image: Classic Volume Control]

Alternative work-around: use another media player, e.g., [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) or [MPC-HC](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases).